# How to draw a plot with mean and CI?

Tags: data-visualization, confidence-interval, stata, matlab

I want to draw a plot in Matlab or Stata. I have a mean and CI for some distribution. there should be a line with the upper end of the line representing the upper CI and the lower end the lower CI and the middle, the average.

I am not sure how to do it or how to search for it. Can anyone kindly help me out ? Thanks.

NB:  is there a way to connect these CI ? (with straight lines ? 3 straight lines)

Comment: You mean like |---------------:---------------| ?

Comment: @whuber : right !

Comment: @whuber: is there a way to connect these CI ? (with straight lines ? 3 straight lines)

Comment: @Ahsan: when you say "connect these CI with 3 straight lines" do you mean you want a line graph with three lines: upper, mean, lower? In most programs you can simply plot this as you would any plot with three variables, with adjustment of the line types, symbols, colors to indicate that the middle one is most important and the outer two are related.

Comment: @Wayne : you are right.. can you send me any links of how to do that ? I am unable to find any...my bad :(  .. Also, I am primarily looking at matlab, however stata is fine too...

Comment: @Ahsan: I refuse to use Matlab and don't know anything about Stata. (I use R.) Was just wanting to clarify your question. Perhaps eric.a.booth's answer works in Stata?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Next to [this correct answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/19757/5644), I would like to add an alternative approach for Stata. This approach can be used if a table containing the means and the limits of the intervals is already available. This approach may also be applied if you prefer a first principles solution to a user-written program.

In the example below, you have a table with means and confidence intervals for 5 variables called x1, x2, x3, x4 and x5. Such a table can be generated by Stata or another software.

```
clear 
input str2 varname mean upper lower
x1 30 25  35
x2 50 20  80
x3 60 50  70
x4 60 55  65
x5 65 55  75
end

encode varname, gen(varname1)
scatter mean varname1, xlabel(, valuelabel) || rcap upper lower varname1
```

If for any reasons whatsoever you want to connect the points by lines, try the following:

```
scatter mean varname1, xlabel(, valuelabel) \\\
        || rcap upper lower varname1 \\\
        || line upper mean lower varname1
```

The triple backslash is used to split up the line. Note that the triple backslash cannot be used Stata's command line.

Comment: @lejohn: is there a way to connect these CI ? (with straight lines ? 3 straight lines)

Comment: Yes, but it does not really make sense in this context.

Comment: @lejohn : well...in the context that I need them, it makes sense...

Comment: @lejohn : thanks a lot for your kind help. was just wondering, what do I do, if I want two of these graphs plotted at the same time (connected lines)

Comment: An anonymous editor suggests that you need to use 3 *forward* slashes (`///`) to split up a command line in Stata.

Answer (score 6):

I can speak for Stata.

First, install the user-written program -ciplot- by typing

```
ssc install ciplot
```

You can obtain detailed help for this command by typing

```
help ciplot
```

Load a sample dataset

```
webuse citytemp
```

then, to show an example, type the following command.

```
ciplot heatdd, by(division) hor
```

[image: Horizontal mean and 95% CI]

or, to plot vertically, just drop the "hor" at the end of the command

[image: Vertical mean and 95% CI]

```
ciplot heatdd, by(division)
```

Comment: is there a way to connect these CI ? (with straight lines ? 3 straight lines)

Answer (score 2):

Ahsan:

You've asked twice about connecting these CIs in response to the examples above.  Building on lejohn's example, here's some ways to show connected CI lines:

```
**********begin
clear 
input str2 varname mean upper lower
x1 30 25  35
x2 50 20  80
x3 60 50  70
x4 60 55  65
x5 65 55  75
end

encode varname, gen(varname1)


*CI line properties
loc prop " msize(large) msymbol(d) lwidth(thick)  "

tw (connected mean varname1, xlabel(, valuelabel) ) ///
    (connected upper varname1, `prop' ) ///
    (connected lower varname1, `prop' )


**Or use lfitci
tw (lfitci mean varname1, xlabel(, valuelabel)) 

**********end
```

Answer (score 1):

If your confidence intervals are symmetric, MATLAB provides the **errorbar(x,ymean,error)** function.